# Regex match all words that start with small letters

Tags: regex, case-sensitive

I have to match all the words that start with small letters. So if I have `main` and `Main`, my regex should only match on `main`. Currently I have `[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` and I test it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/) where it matches `main` but also matches `ain` of `Main`. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Use a word boundary. `\b[a-z]...`.

Answer (score 2):

Give `\b[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` a shot.

`\b` is the indicator for word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it to start matching at the first letter of a word -- the word boundary. If you change it to `\b[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` it ought to work as you expect. If you want it to match an entire word and stop, you can add another word boundary at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add the `\b` word boundary.

```
\b[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\b
```

Answer (score 0):

RegEx you need is

```
/\b[a-z][\w]+/g
```

Here is the [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hL4fZ5)